# qPCR to detect viral load

Tags: lab-techniques

In an experiment qPCR was used to determine viral load. Alongside this conventional PCR was also performed and ran on an agarose gel. However I do not understand why both methods would have been used, any insight would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: Can you please add some more information about the experiment? Or add a link to the reference where you found the description of the experiment. Otherwise this question will be hard to answer, since there may be many reasons to do a conventional PCR.

Comment: It was an experiment we did in the lab. We performed qPCR on samples from 2 patients to test them for HIV. I understand why qPCR was used however I do not understand why we were also asked to perform Conventional PCR alongside this.

Comment: How did the two experiment differ or what did you do with the samples (besides letting the samples from the conventional PCR run on a gel)? Which qPCR machine did you use?

Comment: qPCR primers are typically designed to amplify a single, small (<200 bp) amplicon.  Most modern qPCR machines allow the user to perform a [melt curve analysis](https://www.idtdna.com/pages/education/decoded/article/interpreting-melt-curves-an-indicator-not-a-diagnosis) at the end of the experiment to determine if there is more than one amplicon species.  If you are using an older device without this capability, conventional PCR and gel electrophoresis could be used to determine primer specificity.  As for why the experimenter didn't just load the qPCR product into a gel, perhaps they forgot.